# Downloading images from a url that contains special chars

Tags: java, android, json

```
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
```

now if params equals

> content/uploads/2013/07/\u039d\u03b9\u03ba\u03bf\u03bb\u03ad\u03c4\u03b1-\u2013-Nicoleta.jpg

that it returns null.
I tried using URLEncoder and URLDecoder but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

`URLEncoder` will encode the protocol characters (i.e. `http://`) and result in an invalid url in this case. Try to use:

```
URI uri = new URI(params[0]);
String converted = uri.toASCIIString();
URL url = new URL(converted);
```